# Build external library only once with CMake

Tags: c++, build, cmake

My C++ projects includes the source code of a third-party library (currently as a git submodule).

This library is added to the project by our main CMakelists through the use of `add_subdirectory`, and then the library is linked with the main target.

Here is a reduced version of my current Cmake file :

```
add_subdirectory(foo)
set(FOO_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libfoo/libfoo.so)

add_executable(target main.cpp)
add_dependencies(target foo)
target_link_libraries(target ${FOO_LIBRARY})
```

This library takes a long time to build and, since I don't change its code I need it built only once (per build configuration). But when I clean and rebuild my code it also cleans the library files and recompile them.

I have tried to set the property [`CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/prop_dir/CLEAN_NO_CUSTOM.html) in the library's directory, but according to the documentation it only works for custom command targets.

Is there a mechanism in CMake through which it is possible to specify that this library target needs to be generated only once, or alternatively not cleaned by `make clean` ?

Comment: Since you doesn't use *internal* targets of third-party library, it seems that approach with `ExternalProject_Add`  will be better than `add_subdirectory`. As `ExternalProject_Add` doesn't specify clean rules, CMake won't attempt to clean the library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev said, in your case `ExternalProject_Add` is better than `add_subdirectory`. `add_subdirectory` is good when you want project to be essential part of your build system because target it creates can be used in  in the right-hand-side of the `target_link_libraries()` command while target created by `ExternalProject_Add` cannot.

Here is the approach I used in one of my projects. You try to find required library and build it only if it was not found. I use INTERFACE library to turn FOO_EXTERNAL into a target acceptable by `target_link_libraries()`.

```
add_library(foo INTERFACE)
find_package(foo ${FOO_VER})
if(NOT foo_FOUND)
    include(ExternalProject)
    include(GNUInstallDirs)
    ExternalProject_Add(FOO_EXTERNAL
                    SOURCE_DIR "${FOO_SOURCE_DIR}"
                    BINARY_DIR "${FOO_BINARY_DIR}"
                    INSTALL_DIR "${FOO_INSTALL_DIR}"
                    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}"
                               "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}"
                               "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"

                               "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${FOO_INSTALL_DIR}"
                    )

    add_dependencies(foo FOO_EXTERNAL)
    set(foo_LIBRARY
            "${FOO_INSTALL_DIR}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_PREFIX}foo${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
    set(foo_INCLUDE_DIR "${FOO_INSTALL_DIR}/include")
endif()

target_link_libraries(foo INTERFACE ${foo_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE ${foo_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Answer (score 6):

Based on the excellent answer by @Hikke, I wrote two macros to simplify using external projects.

**Code**

```
include(ExternalProject)

#
#   Add external project.
#
#   \param name             Name of external project
#   \param path             Path to source directory
#   \param external         Name of the external target
#
macro(add_external_project name path)
    # Create external project
    set(${name}_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${path})
    set(${name}_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${path})
    ExternalProject_Add(${name}
        SOURCE_DIR "${${name}_SOURCE_DIR}"
        BINARY_DIR "${${name}_BINARY_DIR}"
        CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}"
                   "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}"
                   "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
                   # These are only useful if you're cross-compiling.
                   # They, however, will not hurt regardless.
                   "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}"
                   "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=${CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}"
                   "-DCMAKE_AR=${CMAKE_AR}"
                   "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}"
                   "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}"
                   "-DCMAKE_RC_COMPILER=${CMAKE_RC_COMPILER}"
                   "-DCMAKE_COMPILER_PREFIX=${CMAKE_COMPILER_PREFIX}"
                   "-DCMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH=${CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH}"
       INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )

endmacro(add_external_project)

#
#   Add external target to external project.
#
#   \param name             Name of external project
#   \param includedir       Path to include directory
#   \param libdir           Path to library directory
#   \param build_type       Build type {STATIC, SHARED}
#   \param external         Name of the external target
#
macro(add_external_target name includedir libdir build_type external)
    # Configurations
    set(${name}_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${libdir})

    # Create external library
    add_library(${name} ${build_type} IMPORTED)
    set(${name}_LIBRARY "${${name}_BINARY_DIR}/${CMAKE_CFG_INTDIR}/${CMAKE_${build_type}_LIBRARY_PREFIX}${name}${CMAKE_${build_type}_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")

    # Find paths and set dependencies
    add_dependencies(${name} ${external})
    set(${name}_INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${includedir}")

    # Set interface properties
    set_target_properties(${name} PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${${name}_LIBRARY})
    set_target_properties(${name} PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${${name}_INCLUDE_DIR})
endmacro(add_external_target)
```

**Explanation**

The first macro creates the external project, which does the entire external build step, while the second step sets the necessary dependencies and defines the interface. Separating the two is important, because most projects have more than one interface/library.

**Example**

Say I have [GoogleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest) as a submodule in my project, located in the `googletest` subfolder. I can use the following interface to define the `gtest` and `gtest_main` macros, very similar to how Googletest itself does it.

```
add_external_project(googletest_external googletest)
add_external_target(gtest googletest/googletest/include googletest/googlemock/gtest STATIC googletest_external)
add_external_target(gtest_main googletest/googletest/include googletest/googlemock/gtest STATIC googletest_external)
```

I can then link my target to googletest much like before:

```
target_link_libraries(target_tests
    gtest
    gtest_main
    # The CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT can be found from `find_package(Threads)`
    # and is required for all but MinGW builds.
    ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}
)
```

This should provide sufficient boilerplate to simplify the actual external build process, even with CMake-driven projects.