# How to set location of output when using ExternalProject_Add in cmake?

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I used `ExternalProject_Add` to add multiple libraries to my project but I cannot set location of output of these libs. `ExternalProject_Add` has a `BINARY_DIR` parameter which setting it to desired location does not work as I expect. Also I set `INSTALL_DIR` but anything changed.

```
ExternalProject_Add (${name}
        SOURCE_DIR "${${name}_SOURCE_DIR}"
        BINARY_DIR "${${name}_BINARY_DIR}"
        CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}"
        "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}"
        "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        )
```

**PS:**

1) I need to collect all libs in the `project/bin/libs` folder in order to use other programs (suppose `project` is the main folder which has `CMakeLists.txt` contained `ExternalProject_Add`. Also libs are in the path `project/lib/third party/libA` through `libf` and `project/lib/MyLibs/lib1` through `lib3`).

2) **Q:** What can do if we need to copy libs (like `libA.dll` and `lib1.dll`) to multiple destinations (like `project/../external_application_A` and `project/../external_application_B`) **using** `project/CMakeLists.txt`?

3) I used *alexander-huszagh* macros from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123948/build-external-library-only-once-with-cmake) (last answer).

Comment: I've only used ExternalProject_Add when dealing with established project that use autotools (automake).  If the project doesn't have any project files, consider create a CMakelist.txt for it, and adding as subdirectory or installed package.

Comment: If it were just one file per external project that you needed to move, something like `INSTALL_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy <file> <destination>` should work. However, this does not seem to work with multiple files. You could also add an argument to `CMAKE_ARGS`, e.g. `"-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<destination>"` and then set `INSTALL_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target install`. This would put all your external libraries into the same folder, if they support that option.

Comment: @jerrylogansquare As you can see in the mentioned link `ExternalProject_Add` is useful to add external libraries which it build just once(if it does not exist compiled and at rebuild time these libs do not recompile). It is very useful to reduce compile time of projects with multiple external libs.